# cxf NullPointerException while deploying on glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, cxf

I'm trying to deploy war on glassfish3 and i get exception:

```
SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [cxf.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-ws.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [cxf.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:253)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [cxf.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-ws.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [cxf.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [cxf.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:202)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.checkOverrideProperties(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor91.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor91.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor91.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor90.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor103.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:509)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1157)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:187)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:147)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:349)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.createJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 56 more
```

here is this offending cxf.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-camel.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<bean name="taskServiceBean" class="com.example.TaskServiceImpl" />

<camelContext id="context" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="serverRoute">
        <from uri="jms:queue:com.example.taskservice" />
        <to uri="direct:TaskServiceServer" />
    </route>

</camelContext>


<jaxws:endpoint id="taskServiceJMS" address="camel://direct:TaskServiceServer" implementor="#taskServiceBean">
</jaxws:endpoint>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelTransportFactory"
    p:camelContext-ref="context" p:bus-ref="cxf">
    <property name="checkException" value="true" />
    <property name="transportIds">
        <list>
            <value>http://cxf.apache.org/transports/camel</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

myConnectionFactory is defined as follows in project that is on classpath:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:comp/env/amqConnectionFactory" />
```

However, the same file can be deployed, even on the same domain after any successfull deployment has been done.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: "nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException" and no stacktrace follows that?

Comment: What happened is that you didn't include a stacktrace, so nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem when upgrading my server from glassfish v3.0.1 to glassfish v3.1.1. 
Seems like there is a bug in the jaxb-osgi.jar in v3.1.1.  http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-860 shows that the fix will be included in glassfish v3.1.2. But at the meantime, I replaced the jaxb-osgi.jar in glassfish v3.1.1 with the jar from glassfifh v3.0.1 and the problem is solved. You should be able to get a newer version of jaxb-osgi.jar that has the fix in as well.